Building C++ with Ninja not parsing file
I'm using sublime text with ubuntu. My build.ninja file looks perfect to me but I get this error when I try build:
ninja
ninja: error: build.ninja:6: expected 'command =' line

Here is my build.ninja file:
cxx = g++
cxxflags = -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra
builddir = build

rule cxx
    command = mkdir -p $builddir && $cxx $cxxflags -c $in -o $out
    description = Compiling $in

rule link
    command = $cxx $in -o $out
    description = Linking $out

build $builddir/hello.o: cxx hello.cpp
build app: link $builddir/hello.o

default app

Using the cat command in ubuntu we can see the exact line formatting:
cat -A build.ninja

cxx = g++$
cxxflags = -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra$
builddir = build$
$
rule cxx$
^Icommand = mkdir -p $builddir && $cxx $cxxflags -c $in -o $out$
^Idescription = Compiling $in$
$
rule link$
^Icommand = $cxx $in -o $out$
^Idescription = Linking $out$
$
build $builddir/hello.o: cxx hello.cpp$
build app: link $builddir/hello.o$
$
default app$

Can anyone tell me what the problem could be?

Rule variables should be indented with spaces. There are already several issues regarding misleading error message produced when tabs are used, i.g. https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1598 @Someprogrammerdude It's other way around: make needs tabs instead of spaces.

Weird. I can't reproduce it, file parses successfully. Ninja 1.12.1, no extra arguments, I just copied your code block. If I create an empty hello.cpp, first error is at linking step.

This question reads as if the ninja file is being hand written? Ninja states that their intent is to to human readable, not human writable. Use CMake to generate your ninja files.

see https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blob/master/doc/manual.asciidoc, ninja isn't supposed to be written directly, you'd be much better off using a ninja generator

I'm writing it manually with help of ChatGPT because I'm try to learn how it works. I'm completely new to ninja.

Then use the tool as the developers intended.
